# Lining up sets of data in Excel (both with unique keys)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

A [related](https://superuser.com/questions/307429/how-do-i-line-up-two-sets-of-data-in-excel) question asks how to line up two sets of data in Excel.  I am struggling to figure out how to do this when you have values in **both** lists which don't exist in the other list.  Ie: how would line up these lists?

```
Position    Occurrences
      8               3
     11               1
     17               2
     18               1
```

and another set of data has

```
Position    Occurrences
      8               1
      9               3
     18               6
```

how can I line it up so that it's

```
Position    Occurrences     Position    Occurrences
      8               3            8              1
                                   9              3
     11               1         
     17               2         
     18               1           18              6
```

You'll note that in this example we have Position's 11 and 17 which are in list 1 but not list 2.  And Position 9 which is in list 2 but not list 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a master list containing all possible values (e.g. 1 to 20 in your case) and look for the corresponding values from the original list:
  - fill numbers 1 - 20 in A2 to A21
  - in column B put formula: `=if(iserror(match(A2,<range1!column1>,0)),"",A2)`
  - formula in column C: `=iferror(vlookup(A2,<range1!columns1:2>,2,false),"")`
  - in columns D and E put the same formulas related for your second range
  - in column F put this formula to check whether any of the ranges has value in the row to let you filtering out empty rows: `=count(C2,D2)>0`